# Resource has been exhausted Google Home

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

From time to time I am seeing `homegraph.devices.requestSync`  throws

```
 Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).
Error: Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).
    at Gaxios._request (/xxx/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:129:23)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async JWT.requestAsync (/xxxxxxx/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:368:18)
```

Where can I find quota details or more formation about this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question here: https://developers.home.google.com/cloud-to-cloud/integration/quotas